# MySQL - select multiple maximum values

Tags: mysql, select, max

I have a table called `order` which contains columns `id`, `user_id`, `price`. I would like to select each user's most expensive order - the order for which that user paid the highest price. I want to select `order.user_id` and `order.price` in the same query.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL - select multiple maximum values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590530/mysql-select-multiple-maximum-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select user_id, max(price) from `order` group by user_id
```

Comment: No, I'm sorry it does work correctly but there's something else I needed too.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT order.user_id, A.price 
FROM `order`
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT user_id, price FROM `order` ORDER BY price DESC) A USING (user_id)
```